# Deploy Windows Phone app via SD card error

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I've developed a app in VS2013. I need to send the .XAP file to my customer by email. He will copy the .XAP file to the phone SD card and install the update. The big problem is that the customer is far away from me, they are a company with just Win7 computers and I can't use any program to help me because all the programs that I know it's possible to update the app just runs on Windows 8! I even tried to install a VirtualBox with Windows 8 on the customer computer but it's not recognize the Windows Phone 8.

My last try was to buy a SD card and install on my Nokia520 and see if I copy the XAP file to it and use the Files app (downloaded from the store) to install the .xap file.

When I try to install, I receive the following message:

> Can't install company app There's a problem with this company app.
>   Contact your company's support person to help

I have a developer account and the phone is unlocked.

Is there a way to publish my app remotely without my customer had Windows 8 installed ? All the programs I need that help me to install and update files on the smartphone (Windows Phone Power Tools, IsoStoreSpy and others just runs on Win8 systems).

I really need to remotely install this app and because the app is for the company's use, I don't want to publish to the Windows Phone App store.

Regards!

Comment: You could publish the app to certain beta users and mention your customer as the beta user.

Comment: @bit Yes, I did it yesterday and I can now send the email to the users, but I still can't install the .xap file through the SD card. I believe that just store apps could be installed by SD card. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install .xap files from your phone's SD card

1. Insert an SD card that contains one or more .XAP files into your phone.
2. In the App list, tap Store Store Tile.
3. Tap More More icon, then tap Install local apps. (If you're running an earlier version of Windows Phone, look for the SD card option instead.)

**Note**
If you've just inserted the SD card or added the .XAP files, you might need to wait a few minutes before you can access your SD card from the Store.

4. Select the apps you want, then tap Install.
5. Installed apps appear in the App list. Depending on the specific app or game, you'll be able to use them as follows:

   - Free apps and games can be used immediately.
   - Paid apps and games that have a trial will be available as a trial version that you can purchase later.
   - Paid apps and games without a trial must be purchased before you can use them.